# Extracting variables from calling the value- Getting Error message in condition

Tags: json, powershell, vnet, convertto-json

I am trying to do validation. checking the deployed values with the given values. I extract the vnet values from Azure resources using RestAPI method and convertto-json from Object because of vnet object is giving me empty object (@{value=System.Object[]}). The following is the Json code I am getting:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "properties": "@{virtualNetworkSubnetId=/subscriptions/<XXXX>/resourceGroups/<XXXX>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<XXXX>/subnets/<XXXX>; ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint=True; state=Ready}",
      "id": "/subscriptions/<XXXX>/resourceGroups/<XXXX>/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/<XXXX>/virtualNetworkRules/<XXXX>",
      "name": "<XXXX>",
      "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/virtualNetworkRules"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following powershell command is to compare the value but getting an error saying $vnet.name and $vnet.id is $null

```
$vnet= ( $vnet | ConvertTo-Json)

   It "has this number of vNet Rules defined: $($config.vnetRules.count)" 
  {
    $vnet.count | Should -Be $config.vnetRules.count    
   }

   #$vnet.count is working and giving an success message

   foreach ($vnetRule in $config.vNetRules) {

    Write-Host $vnet            #-> getting Json 
    Write-Host $vnet.Name       #-> return as Empty($null)
        Write-Host $vnet.value.Name #-> return as Empty($null)
    Write-Host $vnet.id         #-> return as Empty($null)
        Write-Host $vnet.value.id   #-> return as Empty($null)

    it "has a vNet rule named: $($vnetRule.ruleName)" {
        $vnet.name | Should -Be $vnetRule.ruleName
    }

    it "has a vNet Rule Subnet ID of: $($vNetRule.subnetId)" {
        $vnet.value.id | Should -Be $vNetRule.subnetId
    }

}
```

Returns $null.

Comment: Well if `$vnet` is JSON, it will not return anything for `$vnet.Name` since `Name` is not a property of Json object. Its a property of the powershell object.

Comment: I think this may be your problem. You are using the same variable name. `$vnet= ( $vnet | ConvertTo-Json)`.

Comment: I have tried with different variable still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my attempt to recreate your `invoke-restmethod` output, I used your JSON packet as input to create the `$vnet` variable.

I believe the problem is you are using `Write-host` to display the object instead of simply the object name. `Write-host` will attempt to convert the complex object to a string and hence you see the weird output as you can see below. see the difference when i simply out the object?

[image]

Now, `$vnet` has 4 properties `id, name, properties, type` and can be invoked as shown.
In you case, you have converted the variable `$vnet` to `json` and then attempting to display its properties. But `Json` does not have any properties, except `length`. And hence, invoking those properties will give you null.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I am accepting the answer.